# If the interior of two convex manifolds intersect, what is the dimension of their intersection?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds, geometric-topology, convex-geometry

In $\mathbb R^n$, let $A,B$ be two convex manifolds of dimension $a,b$ respectively whose interiors intersect.  It would seem that their intersection is a convex manifold of dimension $\min(a,b)$.  Is that correct?

What if we drop some of the conditions? For example, this would seem to hold true even if $A,B$ are not manifolds, but simply complex sets.  Would it hold true outside of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Think about two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$. More generally, think about sets given by linear conditions.

Comment: @AlexB. That's a clear counterexample, thank you.  What then, is the correct dimensionality? That is, a ball and plane intersect into a disc, whereas two planes intersect in a line.  Is there a formula relating the dimensionality of the intersection to that of the original sets? (I'm restricting to cases where the _interiors_ intersect).

Comment: There is no formula, but there is one for transversal intersections, namely, codimension of the intersection  equals to the sum of codimensions of intersecting submanifolds.

Comment: The reason I suggested that you think about sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by a bunch of linear conditions is that this way you would arrive at the formula just quoted by Moishe Kohan. That is the "generic" case.

Comment: @AlexB. Fascinating.  I'm not familiar with [transversal intersections](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransversalIntersection.html) and the articles I've found use more background than I have.  Is there a simple explanation of what they are -- at least as concerns this context?

Comment: Do you know any linear algebra?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I'm familiar with linear algebra over $\mathbb R^n$: vectors, vector spaces, matrices = linear transformations, rank, nullspace, rowspace, eigenvectors, orthogonality, and the spectral theorem.

Comment: OK, then prove that if $V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, $U, W\subset V$ are linear subspaces whose common span is $V$ then $codim(U\cap W)= codim U + codim W$, where $codim$ denotes codimension in $V$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Great suggestion! I believe I've done so (posted as an answer) - can you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing on Moishe Kohan's suggestion, we first prove the following:

> Prove that if $\mathcal V$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, $\mathcal U, \mathcal W \subset \mathcal V$ are linear subspaces whose common span is $\mathcal V$ then $\operatorname{codim}(\mathcal U \cap \mathcal W)=\operatorname{codim} \mathcal U+ \operatorname{codim}\mathcal W$, where $\operatorname{codim}$ denotes codimension in $\mathcal V$.

For simplicity of discussion, we take $\mathcal V$ for the ambient space.  If $\mathcal A$ is a vector space, there exists a matrix $A$ whose rowspace $R(A)$ is precisely $\mathcal A$. Then $\operatorname{codim} \mathcal A = \dim N(A)$.

Recall that if $A, B$ are two vector spaces such that $A \cap B = \{0\}$, and $C = \operatorname{span}(A, B)$, then $\dim C = \dim A + \dim B$.

Since $\mathcal U, \mathcal W$ span $\mathcal V$, then $N(U) \cap N(W) = \{0\}$, so $\dim N(U) \cap N(W) = \dim N(U) + \dim N(W)$.  Generalizing this result to cases where $\mathcal V$ is not the ambient space but rather an arbitrary finite dimensional real vector space is straightforward.

---

This suggests the following:  Let $A, B$ be two convex sets in $\mathbb R^n$ whose interiors intersect.  Choose an arbitrary point in this interior intersection and call it $O$.  Let $V$ be the set of vectors expressible as $O + \lambda_1 (a - O) + \lambda_2 (b - O)$ for any $a \in A, b \in B$.  Then $$\operatorname{codim} A \cap B = \operatorname{codim} A + \operatorname{codim}  B$$ where $\operatorname{codim}$ is in $V$.

Comment: The sentence "Recall that..." is false as written. You forgot to take the span of the union. Also, empty intersection is nonsense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, both fixed.  What about the "This suggests..." part?

Comment: "Interiors intersect" makes very little sense. You probably mean "relative interiors" (defined as interiors relative to affine spans of the above convex subsets).